# How do I test my app on iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, testing, certificate

I am university student, and i received from school an invitation to apple developer which i created an account and joined the group. I downloaded and installed the  "WWDR intermediate certificate" and installed it, also noticed that they added my device in the provisioning profile.
From here I am lost, were I am not sure what is the next steps I should do

Answer (score 1):

1. Login to the Member Center
2. Go to the provisioning portal
3. Create a developer certificate (different from a distribution cert, which you'll need for AppStore release)
4. Create an App ID (and add a device, if you're doing an ad hoc app)
5. Create, download, and install a provisioning profile
6. Plug your iPhone into your Mac
7. Build your Xcode project for the device (instead of for the simulator)

Answer (score 0):

In the developer portal you should:

Enter your app and give it a name.

Add the app to a provisioning file.

Download the provisioning file

Drag that file into Xcode.

In the organizer-window in Xcode - add the provisioning file to your phone. This might not be necessary since Xcode can automatically download a team provisioning file.

That was from the top of my head. Try search for a guide or tutorial for it, there's plenty of them :)